# How to listen BroadcastReceiver in main activity?

Tags: android

I have broadcast in separated class:

```
class Receiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {}
}
```

How to listen this broadcasrt in main activity?

I have tried:

```
class MainActivity :  AppCompatActivity() {
    private val receiver = Receiver()
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        receiver.onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
          //
        }
    }
}
```

Now I register events like this:

```
override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    registerReceiver(receiver, IntentFilter(TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED))
}
```

I tried this in activity:

```
private val broadcastReceiver:BroadcastReceiver = (object :BroadcastReceiver(){
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {

        val ltInflater = layoutInflater
        val layout: View = ltInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast, findViewById(R.id.toast_layout))
        val image = layout.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageView)
```

}

So, I get error because I can not get access to layout in this step

Comment: You should add `Receiver` in `AndroidManifest`. Also you need to send Broadcast via `Intent`.

Comment: Could you share an example and how then to use it in main activity

Comment: @MamaBaba :  Register BroadcastReceiver in Activity using `registerReceiver` instead of calling `onReceive` . check https://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Kotlin_Android_Broadcast_Intents_and_Broadcast_Receivers example

Comment: Okay I did this: `<receiver android:name=".Receiver" >
        </receiver>` what next?

Comment: I want to use receiver in separate class (logic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a broadCast receiver in the main activity like this

```
val broadcastReceiver:BroadcastReceiver = (object :BroadcastReceiver(){
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        val layout: View = ltInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast, findViewById(R.id.toast_layout))       
        val image = layout.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageView)       
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
    }
})
```

and you need to have string that's common between both the class that's going to broadcast the intent and the broadcast receiver let's call it key

```
val key = keyTelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED
```

you have to register the receiver to start receiving intents like this (do this in onCreate())

```
var intentFilter = IntentFilter(MainActivity.key);
registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
```

Comment: It is unclear for me, what is key? where to get it? And why do you use `sendBroadcast(Intent(MainActivity.key))`?

Comment: key is just a string that Identifes the intent that you are going to broadcast you make it up

Comment: You did not get me, I want to use broadcast in activity to set a new layout as toast message

Comment: my bad but in your case this seems to be your keyTelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED

Comment: In receiver class where I get message I need to use this code:

`val ltInflater = layoutInflater
        val layout: View = ltInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast, findViewById(R.id.toast_layout))
        val image = layout.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageView)
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)` 

so, that is whyI try to move broadcast callback in main activity to be able access to layout

Comment: and skip the last part about the broadcasting

Comment: Check my prev comment please

Comment: you don't need to create a separate class and texted BroadcastReciever you can do it like this

Comment: Thank you, I will try to apply this now

Comment: You need to create a broadCast receiver in the main activity like this.
Inside onCreate or inside onStart method?

Comment: make the braodcastReceiver as a global variable call the registerReciever() in on create

Comment: Problem is if it is global I can not use this inside: `      val ltInflater = layoutInflater
        val layout: View = ltInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast, findViewById(R.id.toast_layout))`

Comment: define the variable globally intialize it in onCreate()